# How to add radio buttons on the list

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I developed a shopping list app following [this](http://www.javacjava.com/AndroidTutorials.aspx) tutorial. Now after completing the whole tutorial i want to add radio button to every list of items so that it can be helpful to know which items are already purchased from the shopping list. But I do not have proper idea how that is done. if you can guide me that would be helpful.

**Here is my Source Code**

```
package com.dopenets.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> shoppingList = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
    ListView lv = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        shoppingList = getArrayVal(getApplicationContext());
        Collections.sort(shoppingList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shoppingList);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                if (selectedItem.trim().equals(shoppingList.get(position).trim())) {
                    removeElement(selectedItem, position);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Removing Element", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_add){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Item");
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            builder.setView(input);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    shoppingList.add(preferredCase(input.getText().toString()));
                    Collections.sort(shoppingList);
                    storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static String preferredCase (String original)
    {
        if (original.isEmpty())
            return original;
        return original.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    public static void storeArrayVal( ArrayList<String> inArrayList, Context context)
    {
        Set<String> WhatToWrite = new HashSet<String>(inArrayList);
        SharedPreferences WordSearchPutPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("dbArrayValues", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = WordSearchPutPrefs.edit();
        prefEditor.putStringSet("myArray", WhatToWrite);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }

    public static ArrayList getArrayVal( Context dan)
    {
        SharedPreferences WordSearchGetPrefs = dan.getSharedPreferences("dbArrayValues",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<String>();
        tempSet = WordSearchGetPrefs.getStringSet("myArray", tempSet);
        return new ArrayList<String>(tempSet);
    }

    public void removeElement(String selectedItem, final int position){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Remove " + selectedItem + "?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                shoppingList.remove(position);
                Collections.sort(shoppingList);
                storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Android Developer which explains how to implement Radio Buttons. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Add the Radio Group in the Layout with the Radio Button options as shown in the example.  Because it sounds like you're not doing any action when they are clicked you could just add the Radio Group (with radio buttons) to your simple_list_item_1 and then when calling onRadioButtonClicked have it only change the radio to show it as checked (this code is added to your MainActivity):

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
1.create custom layout with radiobutton or checkbox and textview (xml)
2.create custom adapter with custom class
3. custom class which contains string productname,boolean checked;

Your Custom Layout

    <RelativeLayout>

    <RadioButton></RadioButton>
    <TextView></TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

Your Custom Class

    public class mycustomclass
    {
    public String ProductName;
    public boolean productChecked;
    }

Your Custom Adapter

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<mycustomclass>
{
 //your code
}

update mycustom class boolean field when radio checked and unchecked
```